# estimate involving Gaussian data

Tags: inequalities, integration, harmonic-analysis

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$, $d\geq 1$ and $p>\frac{2}{d}$. For any $R>0$ and any $0<s<\frac{dp}{2}-1$

\begin{align}
&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{|x|>R}\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2} \right)^{\frac{d(p+2)}{4}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2(p+2)}{4(1+t^{2})}} \, dx \, dt\\
&\lesssim R^{-s}\int\int |x|^s \left(\frac{1}{1+t^2} \right)^{\frac{d(p+2)}{4}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2(p+2)}{4(1+t^{2})}} \, dx \, dt\\
 &\lesssim R^{-s}\int (1+t^2)^{-\frac{dp}{4}+\frac{s}{2}} \, dt\\
&\lesssim_{s} R^{-s}
\end{align}

Trying to understand the sequence of inequalities above, the first one simply applies Chebyshev's inequality. However, from the second to the third one,  I don't understand the upper bound on the exponential function that is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R} $Making the substitution $x=cu$ with
\begin{equation}
    c:=\Big(\frac{4(1+t^2)}{p+2}\Big)^{1/2},
\end{equation}
we see that the inner integral in the second line of your four-line display is
\begin{align*}
    &\Big(\frac1{1+t^{2}}\Big)^{d(p+2)/4} \int_{\R^d}|x|^s e^{-|x|^2/c^2}\,dx \\ 
    &=\Big(\frac1{1+t^{2}}\Big)^{d(p+2)/4} \int_{\R^d}c^s|u|^s e^{-|u|^2}\,c^d du \\ 
    &\asymp \Big(\frac1{1+t^{2}}\Big)^{d(p+2)/4}\,c^{s+d} \\ 
    &\asymp (1+t^2)^{-dp/4+s/2}.\quad\Box  
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice answer, thanks.